# How to install Andengine in my eclipse?

Tags: android, installation, andengine

I am new to android... I want to create simple android game using Andengine. Could you tell how to install Andengine in eclipse....I'm using eclipse on linux.

**Edit:**

Andengine is installed but I get this error message in logcat:

```
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): java.io.FileNotFoundException: ggg
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at android.content.res.AssetManager.
  openAsset(Native Method)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at android.content.res.AssetManager
 .open(AssetManager.java:313)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at android.content.res.AssetManager
 .open(AssetManager.java:287)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
.source.AssetTextureSource.<init>(AssetTextureSource.java:46)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
 .region.TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(TextureRegionFactory.java:66)
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at org.anddev.andengine.examples.minimal
   .AndEngineMinimalExample.onLoadResources(AndEngineMinimalExample.java:59)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity
 .BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:158)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity
 .BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:83)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at com.android.internal.policy.impl
 .PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:1981)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at android.view.View
 .dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3788)
 02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at android.view.ViewGroup
 .dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:658)
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at   
  android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501): at
  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   02-09 00:36:53.562: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main
   (Native Method)
   02-09 00:36:53.821: DEBUG/dalvikvm(501): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1797 objects / 
   148120 bytes in 173ms
   02-09 00:36:54.160: DEBUG/libEGL(501): egl.cfg not found, using default config
   02-09 00:36:54.230: DEBUG/libEGL(501): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
   02-09 00:36:54.425: DEBUG/AndEngine(501): onSurfaceCreated
   02-09 00:36:54.441: DEBUG/AndEngine(501): RENDERER: Android PixelFlinger 1.3
   02-09 00:36:54.500: DEBUG/AndEngine(501): VERSION: OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
   02-09 00:36:54.511: DEBUG/AndEngine(501): EXTENSIONS: GL_OES_byte_coordinates 
   GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_read_format  
   GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_matrix_get 
   GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture 
   GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two   
   GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane 
   GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap 
   02-09 00:36:54.531: DEBUG/AndEngine(501): EXTENSIONS_VERXTEXBUFFEROBJECTS = false
   02-09 00:36:54.531: DEBUG/AndEngine(501): EXTENSIONS_DRAWTEXTURE = true
   02-09 00:36:54.541: DEBUG/AndEngine(501): onSurfaceChanged: pWidth=480  pHeight=320
   02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501): Failed loading Bitmap in 
   AssetTextureSource. AssetPath: ggg
   02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501): java.io.FileNotFoundException: ggg
   02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
   02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
   02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
   02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
   org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.source
  .AssetTextureSource.onLoadBitmap(AssetTextureSource.java:95)
   02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
  .Texture$TextureSourceWithLocation.onLoadBitmap(Texture.java:364)
  02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
  .Texture.writeTextureToHardware(Texture.java:208)
  02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
  org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:175)
  02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
  .TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:136)
  02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine
 .onDrawFrame(Engine.java:508)
  02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
 .RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:148)
  02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
 .GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
 02-09 00:36:54.630: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
 .GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501): Error loading: AssetTextureSource(ggg)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 TextureSource: AssetTextureSource(ggg) returned a null Bitmap.
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
 .Texture.writeTextureToHardware(Texture.java:211)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
 org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:175)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:136)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at 
 org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:508)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:148)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
 02-09 00:36:54.751: ERROR/AndEngine(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
 .GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
 02-09 00:36:54.793: WARN/dalvikvm(501): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught 
 exception (group=0x4001d800)
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 TextureSource: AssetTextureSource(ggg) returned a null Bitmap.
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501): at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
 .Texture.writeTextureToHardware(Texture.java:211)
  02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501):at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
  .Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:175)
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501):   at 
 org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture
 .TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:136)
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine
 .Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:508)
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
 .RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:148)
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
 .GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
 02-09 00:36:54.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(501):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view
 .GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
 02-09 00:36:54.983: WARN/ActivityManager(66):Force finishing 
 activityorg.anddev.andengine.examples.minimal/.AndEngineMinimalExample
 02-09 00:36:55.661: DEBUG/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2704 objects / 
 163368 bytes in 265ms
02-09 00:36:55.743: INFO/WindowManager(66): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
02-09 00:36:55.781: INFO/ActivityManager(66): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 
loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=13}
02-09 00:36:56.240: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity pause timeout for 
HistoryRecord{43fd2338 org.anddev
.andengine.examples.minimal/.AndEngineMinimalExample}
 02-09 00:36:56.922: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(288): showStatusIcon on inactive 
 InputConnection
  02-09 00:36:57.416: WARN/WindowManager(66): Window freeze timeout expired.
  02-09 00:36:57.416: WARN/WindowManager(66): Force clearing orientation change: 
  Window{43fecea8 StatusBarExpanded paused=false}
  02-09 00:36:57.431: WARN/WindowManager(66): Force clearing orientation change: 
   Window{43fba7b0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}
   02-09 00:36:59.090: DEBUG/dalvikvm(335): GC_EXPLICIT freed 85 objects / 3560bytes   
  in 12084ms
 02-09 00:36:59.891: DEBUG/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1126 objects / 61592 bytes 
 in 399ms
 02-09 00:37:07.941: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity destroy timeout for 
 HistoryRecord{43fd2338 org.anddev.andengine.examples.minimal/
 .AndEngineMinimalExample}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the `andengine.jar` to your lib folder in your project (if you don't have one create it)

then add the jar on the project build path

there you have it, you succesfully installed andengine

Comment: Not applicable to the newer versions of AndEngine. AndEngine is no longer exported as a JAR. See here: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Answer (score 1):

How to get full sources in true way

```
cd EclipseWorkspace/
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andengine/ AndEngine
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginelivewallpaperextension/ AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginemodplayerextension/ AndEngineMODPlayerExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginemultiplayerextension/ AndEngineMultiplayerExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginemultitouchextension/ AndEngineMultiTouchExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/ AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andengineaugmentedrealityextension/ AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginesvgtextureregionextension/ AndEngineSVGTextureRegionExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginetexturepackerextension/ AndEngineTexturePackerExtension
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/ AndEngineExamples
mkdir AndEngine/res
mkdir AndEngineLiveWallpaperExtension/res
mkdir AndEngineMODPlayerExtension/res
mkdir AndEngineMultiplayerExtension/res
mkdir AndEngineMultiTouchExtension/res
mkdir AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/res
mkdir AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension/res
mkdir AndEngineSVGTextureRegionExtension/res
mkdir AndEngineTexturePackerExtension/res
```

then import all project into eclipse's workspace and run `AndEngineExamples`